# Not able to get particluar sequence in C but am able to get it in Python

Tags: python, c, while-loop, stdio

I am trying to get a very simple and basic logic up and running using the C language. The following code gets it right on python, but I am not able to get the same results using C.

```
//Python Code
a = 2
while True:
    a=a*2
    print(a)
```

With the above Python code I am able to generate the particular sequence, but with the following C code I am not able to generate the same results.

```
//C Code
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
long int a = 2;
while (1){
    a=a*2;
    printf(a);
}
return 0;
}
```

I am getting 0 infinitely. Why am I not able to get the sequence in C.

**EDIT:** I am running this program with slightly modified code on an Arduino, so I can't use printf.

Comment: `printf("%ld\n", a);` instead of `printf(a);`

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, and for the love of Ritchie, **READ the documentation of a function that you want to use!**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answerable by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` in C is *not* the same as `print` in Python. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is a page describing how to use `printf`. Basically, you provide a format string describing where, what, and how to print the arguments, and then a variable number of arguments to be printed. You want to use `printf("%ld\n", a);`.

Comment: Please understand that I won't be able to use printf() in the program as it will be running on an Arduino. The printf() function was just a reference/stub for another function [Serial.println()].

Comment: First off, that's very important information to not include. Second, read the documentation for that function. If it doesn't match the documentation, then submit a question regarding that function. However, if they aliased printf, it likely has very similar usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int count, n, t1=0, t2=1, display=0;
  printf("Enter number of terms: "); /** Series for how many terms **/
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Fibonacci Series: %d+%d+", t1, t2); 
  count=2;
  while (count<n)  
  {
      display=t1+t2;
      t1=t2;
      t2=display;
      ++count;
      printf("%d+",display);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please understand that I won't be able to use printf() in the program as it will be running on an Arduino. The printf() function was just a reference/stub for another function [Serial.println()].

Answer (score 0):

The sequence that you're printing is not the fibonacci sequence. It is a geometric sequence with ratio 2. See Wikipedia: [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), [Geometric sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Assuming that you actually want the sequence 2,4,8....,

The usage of printf is different. Use

```
printf("%ld", a);
```

Also C doesn't handle integers over 2^32. Using long, it may handle up to 2^64, But either case you would get an overflow, ie. the numbers will eventually get out of range after generating 63 numbers. Python has builtin Big Integers, C doesn't.

Comment: @ Vishal, Use an external Big Integer Library such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org) or [InfInt](https://github.com/sharan01/infint). I would recommend InfInt since it is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you are using the other `print()` on Arduino wrong.. post this on Arduino tags and see.